# Convert iPhone app to universal binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPhone game and I want to convert the project into a universal one. In fact, I have done so already by adjusting the target.
The problem is: For example the UIButtons don't resize and don't relocate.

Question: What is the correct way to create a button so that it automatically adjusts its size if the universal app is run on the Pad?

At the moment I'm making buttons like so:

```
    [self setSettingsButton:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]];
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 121, 30, 180)];
    [settingsButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingsButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prefButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:settingsButton];
```

Well yes, obviously, the positions and sizes are absolute when they should be relative but my question is: **how to make them relative**?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways in this situation:

1)

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 121, 30, 180)];
}
else {
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(131, 145, 60, 250)]; // your iPad values
}
```

2)

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds; // Here we get VC views frame size
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectZero;
buttonsFrame.origin.x = bounds.size.width * 1.0/3.0;   // Yours calculations
buttonsFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.width * 4.0/5.0;   //
buttonsFrame.size.width = 240;                         //
buttonsFrame.size.height = 300;                        //
[settingsButton setFrame:buttonsFrame];
```

Hope this'll help!

Comment: @Zapko: Thanks, this looks as if it'd work. But I was wondering if there isn't any elegant solution. Do Apple really expect you to do all this? I there nothing "automatic" or "relative"?

Comment: @Matt: There is a autoresizingMask property and it is great when you deal with interface rotation, but in this situation I'm not sure it'll work. Maybe if you make your custom view, init it with fixed frame and fixed coordinates of subviews, assign right autoresizingMask values to the subviews. And then set its frame to appropriate size for iPad or iPhone in loadView method of your view controller...

Comment: @zapko:  It tried a button with fixed proportions and the autoresize mask last year and the property was ignored.  The property seems to only matter after the view loads and something changes.

Comment: @Zapko: thank you! You really helped me. I think I'll do this for the buttons and what MystikSpiral suggests for the windows.

Comment: @Zapko: actually, if I want to provide for Retina as well I guess there would have to be 3 cases. I just googled and found [this](http://www.machwerx.com/2011/01/31/retina-display/).

Comment: @Matt: not actually : ) if you write for Retina display coordinates are the same, cause since iphone 4, all graphics stuff in UIKit goes with coordinates in points, not pixels (CoreGraphics is still in pixels). So the size of all iphones have screen size of 320x400 points. They added a special property `scale` for some classes, for example UIView now have `contentScaleFactor` property for these purposes. All mappings goes inside of UIKit, so all you have to wary is your images, & you can change them without interfering in code simply by adding double-sized images with @2x addition to name.

Comment: @Zapko: oh, I read this somewhere, no idea how I could forget something so fundamental! I love it when people know what they're doing ; )

Answer (score 1):

You can go the if/else route zapko suggests or you can set the main window for each device in the project settings.  This will at least allow you to isolate the code for the device outside an if/else block and in my experience it is cleaner to maintain.

Have you also accounted for the Retina display?  I would think the same issue would hit when you test on the standard display vs. the Retina display as well.  Since you are creating a game this may not be an option, but adding the buttons to your view via IB will give the app the ability to scale across screens.

Comment: I have not accounted for the Retina display but I have tested it and the plain iPhone version works fine on the Retina display. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You have to Design for both iphone as well as ipad is the best option.otherwise you have to check the device is iphone or ipad([UIDevice currentDevice].model) and then you have to set frame for both

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].model == iPhone) {
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(38, 121, 30, 180)];
}
else {
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(131, 145, 60, 250)];
}
```

or

create a universal app you have to design for both iphone page as well as ipad page.